# Annotate with unicode mathematical italic capital letters and superscript

Tags: r, plot, text

I would like to:

1. Use the unicode mathematical italic capital letters E (U+1D438), Y (U+1D44C), and X (U+1D44B)
2. Incorporate superscript

Desired style:

[image]

```
ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=3.5, y=7.5, label = "\u1D438[\u1D44C^\u1D44B=1]")
```

Update 1, new attempts:

```
library(ggtext)

test <- tibble(x=3.5, y=7.5, 
               label = "[<sup>=1</sup>]")

ggplot() + 
# attempt with ggtext
  geom_richtext(data = test,
                color = "transparent", # gets rid of box outline
                fill = "transparent",  # gets rid of box fill
                aes(x=x, y=y, label = label)) +
# from jay.sf: correct superscript but not correct unicode
  annotate(geom = "text", x=3.5, y=3.5, 
           label = bquote(italic(E)*'['*italic(Y)^{italic(x)==1}*']'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `bquote` also works with `ggplot2`.

```
plot.new()
text(.5, .5, label=bquote(italic(E)*'['*italic(Y)^{italic(x)==1}*']'), cex=2, family='serif')
```

[image]

Comment: This gets me closer, thanks. I'm still trying to figure out the correct characters (e.g., U+1D438 not U+0045 for E as shown in your helpful example).

Comment: @EricGreen Did you mean fonts with serifs? See update.

Comment: I think that looks like it!